# iPhone simulator 4.3 with xcode 4 is not showing current location

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator

I have xcode 4 and iphone simulator 4.3. i have downloaded sample project from apple developer website which shows current location. So code is absolutely OK.I have mac mini with wifi on. I have tested that project and once it run. but after that despite of many attempts it does not show location and gives error finding location.

What will be the reason of it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't get location on simulator. So try on a device. CLLocation class is hardware specific.

Comment: No, it was showing location on my iphone simulator for one day. but without doing anything same application didnot show any location after that.

Comment: How do you think it would get the location without a GPS device?

Comment: with due respect to your experience and knowledge i think because GPS is not only way to get location information. it can take location information from Wifi and ip addresses as well.

Comment: Thats true, can you paste the link to the source? Some location services require the presence of specific hardware on the given device. For example, heading information is available only for devices that contain a hardware compass. This class defines several methods that you can use to determine which services are currently available.

Comment: Download the sample code from here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html and i have used other one as well. i.e. http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/ Both were running for 1 day only

Comment: Did you read the blog post ? The app will log location events to the console. For best results, run this on an iPhone and not the sim; the sim doesn’t provide real location data and, as far as I’ve ever been able to tell, only ever has one update event.

Comment: Ok So you mean sim only showed once location. its by default. and i have to test it on actual device. Ok.

Comment: Thats what is written in the blog mentioned by you.

Comment: @Parveen i have asked you in the morning as well. Can you please reply to question regarding implementing textFieldA and textFieldB in classC. I will really appreciate because i have asked this question twice but nobody is able to sort it out nor me despite of saveral attempts.

Comment: Reply to my comment in that question.

Comment: @Manjinder - I want to get clarification on that question. Reply to my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

The location should be defaulting to Cupertino.

In Xcode 4.2/iOS5 beta, you can specify a location to test with for the sim.

Answer (score 0):

It did the same to me: it showed the location at first, then I installed the xcode 4.2 beta, then when I went back to 4.1 location was not showing anymore and CLLocationManager was throwing an location error.

I did the following, and the problem was fix (I don't know if both actions are required or only one will suffice, because now it works and can't reproduce):

Run te simulator then:

- unplug the network cable
- change the device to iPhone (retina): Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina)

I did this by mistake, and it fixed the location on my iMac.