# how to get user current location in simulator in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am getting user location from this method

```
/*Region and Zoom*/
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

CLLocation *location1 = [locationManager location];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [location1 coordinate];

location.latitude = location.latitude;
location.longitude = location.longitude;
region.span=span;
region.center = location;

/*Geocoder Stuff*/

MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder=[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
geoCoder.delegate = self;
[geoCoder start];
mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

This works perfectly but when I try to run this code in simulator then it gets crashed at the point of `[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];` this tells it doesn't get the latitude and longitude values. So how can I make this code run in simulator perfectly.

I have to make this code run in simulator, is it possible?

Comment: simulator does not show current location

Comment: yes i know that but i have to do that so can it is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946966/iphone-simulator-4-3-with-xcode-4-is-not-showing-current-location

Comment: I also found same problem like u have. I didn't able to find current location in simulator.
You can refer [this](http://www.bolderimage.com/blog/mobile/coordinates-using-the-iphone-simulator).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On iOS5 Simulator by default you it will show some location in USA. If you want to change that location, in iOS Simulator menu, go to Debug -> Location -> Custom Location.
There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly. This works with mapkit and also with CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 13):

try this path-

Go to product->Edit Scheme->Options->select Allow Location simulation

it won't be your exact location! But at least you can verify your code is working.